# How could I merge two square matrix into one square matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, merge

I have two large square matrices (100X100) (e.g. A and B), I want to merge them into one square matrix(200*200) as C. The Id are random and they are different between the two matrices. See the attachments, thanks in advance.

merging square matrix

[image]

**data**

```
A <- matrix(c(4,12.5,23.9,12.5,6,11.3,13.9,11.3,9), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(c("1","3","6"), c("1","3","6"))) 
B <- matrix(c(5,10.2,9.3,10.2,7,8.5,9.3,8.5,8), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(c("2","4","5"), c("2","4","5")))
```

Comment: Please do not post data as images. Copy them directly into the question in an easily reproducible way (i.e., with `dput`). Please show what code you have tried and what your expected output is

Comment: A <- matrix(c(4,12.5,23.9,12.5,6,11.3,13.9,11.3,9), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE,
            dimnames =  list(c("1","3","6"),
                             c("1","3","6")))
B <- matrix(c(5,10.2,9.3,10.2,7,8.5,9.3,8.5,8), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE,
            dimnames =  list(c("2","4","5"),
                             c("2","4","5")))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps more verbose, but say you are working with two dataframes:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  row_id = c(1, 3, 6),
  v1 = c(4, 12.5, 13.9),
  v3 = c(12.5, 6, 11.3),
  v6 = c(23.9, 11.3, 9),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  row_id = c(2, 4, 5),
  v2 = c(5, 10.2, 9.3),
  v4 = c(10.2, 7, 8.5),
  v5 = c(9.3, 8.5, 8),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Then you could do the following (**updated**):

```
df1 <- df1 %>% 
  `colnames<-`(c('row_id', paste0('V', df1$row_id))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols=!row_id, names_to = 'column', values_to = 'val') %>% 
  mutate(col_id = readr::parse_number(column), .keep='unused')

df2 <- df2 %>% 
  `colnames<-`(c('row_id', paste0('V', df2$row_id))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols=!row_id, names_to = 'column', values_to = 'val') %>% 
  mutate(col_id = readr::parse_number(column), .keep='unused')

df_new <- bind_rows(df1, df2)

size = max(c(df1$row_id, df2$row_id))
df_final <- matrix(0, nrow=size, ncol=size)

for (i in 1:dim(df_new)[1]) {
  df_final[df_new$row_id[i], df_new$col_id[i]] <- df_new$val[i]
}
```

If you want to see just the relevant cells, you can reduce the matrix:

```
data.frame(df_final) %>% 
  filter_all(any_vars(. != 0)) %>% 
  select_if(colSums(.) != 0)

#    X10  X20  X30  X40 X50  X60
# 1  4.0  0.0 12.5  0.0 0.0 23.9
# 2  0.0  5.0  0.0 10.2 9.3  0.0
# 3 12.5  0.0  6.0  0.0 0.0 11.3
# 4  0.0 10.2  0.0  7.0 8.5  0.0
# 5  0.0  9.3  0.0  8.5 8.0  0.0
# 6 13.9  0.0 11.3  0.0 0.0  9.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Hi William, thanks for your answer. here you read each column/row as V1, V3, V6(df1), when I have 1000 id like 49901, 49905, etc for df1 and 49902, 49902, 49904, 49906 for df2, then how can I solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking that the column names don't always match the row_id? In that case you can go with `colnames(df1) <- c('row_id', paste0('V', df1$row_id))` and `colnames(df2) <- c('row_id', paste0('V', df2$row_id))`.

Comment: Thanks, sir, Now the dimension of df_new is  2000000 (1000*1000*2) and df_final <- matrix(0, 2000,2000). but when I run   for (i in 1:dim(df_new)[1]) {
  df_final[df_new$row_id[i], df_new$col_id[i]] <- df_new$val[i]
} command I found following error  Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, df_new$row_id[i], df_new$col_id[i], value = df_new$val[i]) :
  subscript out of bounds

Comment: Dear William,

df1 <- data.frame(
  row_id = c(10, 30, 60),
  v10 = c(4, 12.5, 13.9),
  v30 = c(12.5, 6, 11.3),
  v60 = c(23.9, 11.3, 9),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  row_id = c(20, 40, 50),
  v20 = c(5, 10.2, 9.3),
  v40 = c(10.2, 7, 8.5),
  v50 = c(9.3, 8.5, 8),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)



If you use this data set you will find similar error

Comment: I see the issue. I have updated the answer - let me know if there are still issues.

Comment: Thanks for helping me to solve the problem.

So here now I have three data frame df1 (n1xn1), df2 (n2xn2) and df_new ((n1+n2) x (n1+n2)).
In df_new all the elements are 0.
The final matrix is df_final, which contains values from df1, df2, and df_new.
I think this is called matrix stiffness. So, what would be the equation for df_final?
Sorry for asking too many questions. As  I am very early stage of learning matrix algebra.

Answer (score 1):

If the col and row names are the index of C, then something like this could work:

```
C <- matrix(0, nrow = nrow(A)+nrow(B), ncol = ncol(A)+ncol(B))

C[as.numeric(rownames(A)), as.numeric(colnames(A))] <- A
C[as.numeric(rownames(B)), as.numeric(colnames(B))] <- B
```

Data:

```
A <- matrix(c(4,12.5,23.9,12.5,6,11.3,13.9,11.3,9), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE,
            dimnames =  list(c("1","3","6"),
                             c("1","3","6")))
B <- matrix(c(5,10.2,9.3,10.2,7,8.5,9.3,8.5,8), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE,
            dimnames =  list(c("2","4","5"),
                             c("2","4","5")))
```

Comment: Thank you very much